# Different Linux permissions for two users

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I have a small problem I can't seem to get it right.

I have user1 and user2 and a folder, but I'd like user1 to have full access and user2 to have read only access..

Checking online and looking at the current permissions I can see you can have a user and a group but I can't see how to separate these two roles out? Is this even possible?

I'm running Ubuntu Server but not sure that's making any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User1 is the owning user, a group that User2 is a member of is the owning group, set permissions to 750